# CXF Framework 3.x version

Tags: spring, cxf

I am migrating to spring4 and am using these jars

- org.apache.cxf - cxf-api
- org.apache.cxf - cxf-bundle
- org.apache.cxf - cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs

I came to know that CXF3.x versions are compatible with spring4. Can I use the same versioned jars for all three like CXF3.x.y , if so which version I can use? If not which versions I should go with for errorless code?

Answer (score 0):

cxf-api and cxf-bundle no longer exist in CXF 3.x, so just use cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs.